# .modal() function not working in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, single-page-application, angular8

On Click, `"$("#Popup").modal('show')"` is not working.

**HTML**

```
<a class="btn-profile-login" data-target="#Popup" (click)="loginBtn()">{{SignText}}</a>
```

**TS**

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap"; 

export class SampleComponent implements OnInit{
    loginBtn() {
        $("#Popup").modal('show');
    }
}
```

**Error Message:**

> TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_9__(...).modal is not a
>   function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow these step

```
npm install jquery --save
npm install @types/jquery --save
```

Then in scripts section in architect => build of angular.json file we add path for jquery lib

```
"scripts": [
  "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"
]
```

Then modify  tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "types": ["jquery"] // addd jquery here
  },
  "exclude": ["test.ts", "**/*.spec.ts"]
}
```

Then you can remove this import since you already have type definition of jquery

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
```

Comment: So what ? He is asking how to use jquery in angular. I didn't even recommend him to do that. Try to be polite :)

Comment: Please stop :) .have a nice day

Comment: @TonyNgo getting error : TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCheckConfig' of undefined

Comment: @TonyNgo When code flow goes to the code snippet : $("#Popup").modal('show'); kindly help on this. I am new to angular

Comment: @TonyNgo Error Msg : ProfileComponent.html:19 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'typeCheckConfig' of undefined
    at Modal._getConfig (modal.js:272)
    at new Modal (modal.js:131)
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (modal.js:565)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2)
    at k.fn.init._jQueryInterface [as modal] (modal.js:559)
    at ProfileComponent.loginBtn (profile.component.ts:164)
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (ProfileComponent.html:19)
    at handleEvent (core.js:36759)
    at callWithDebugContext (core.js:38377)

Comment: @TonyNgo: Thanks Tony . Including 'import * as bootstrap from "bootstrap";''in app.module.ts resolved the issue.

Comment: Acctually you dont need to do that. You can import bootstrap in your angular.json  like this https://github.com/ngohungphuc/Presentation/blob/master/Angular%20Workshop/src/starting-point/GoogleDriveClone/GoogleDriveClone/ClientApp/angular.json#L38

Answer (score 1):

Use ngx-bootstrap https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/ It is Angular Bootstrap components that do not require jQuery. It is the official way to use Bootstrap with Angular, you should avoid to include jquery in angular apps when possible

All the best.

Answer (score 0):

you need to include `jQuery` in `index.html` and in your `component` you need to

```
declare var $: any;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"scripts": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" ]
```

This worked for me in angular.json